# Print sum to n numbers

Tags: c++, printing, numbers, sum

Here is my question...

Input a number n from the user.  The program should output **the sum of all numbers from 1 to n NOT including the multiples of 5**.

For example if the user inputs 13 then the program should compute and print the sum of the numbers: 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 11 12 13  (note 5,10 are not included in the sum)

i have made the following program but it is not working..
can any one help me THANK YOU in advance...

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int inputnumber = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int count= 1;
        cout<<"Enter the number to print the SUM : ";
        cin>>inputnumber;

        while(count<=inputnumber)
        {
            if (count % 5!=0)
            {
                sum = sum + count;
            }

        }   count = count +1;
        cout<<"the sum of the numbers are :   "<<sum;

    }
```

Comment: I don't recognize the error  "not working".

Answer (score 0):

You should increment `count` inside the loop, not outside it:

```
while(count<=inputnumber)
{
    if (count % 5!=0)
    {
        sum = sum + count;
    }
    count = count +1; // here
}
```

Note, by the way, that using a `for` loop would be much more convenient here. Additionally, `sum = sum + count` could be shorthanded to `sum += count`.

```
for (int count = 1; count <= inputnumber; ++count)
{
    if (count % 5 != 0)
    {
        sum += count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the count+1 inside your while loop. also add !=0 tou your if statement.

```
  while(count<=inputnumber)
        {
            if (count % 5!=0)
            {
                sum = sum + count;
            }
       count = count +1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a loop at all:

The sum 1..n is

```
n * (n+1) / 2;
```

the sum of the multiples of 5 not above n is

```
 5 * m * (m+1) / 2
```

where `m = n/5` (integer devision). The result is therefore

```
n * (n+1) / 2 - 5 * m * (m+1) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

In my condition,checks **n** value is not equal to zero and % logic

```
int sum = 0;
int n = 16;
for(int i=0 ; i < n ;i++) {
    if( i%5 != 0){
        sum += i;
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's apply some maths. We'll use a formula that allows us to sum an arithmetic progression. This will make the program way more efficient with bigger numbers.

**sum = n(a1+an)/2**

*Where sum is the result, n is the inpnum, a1 is the first number of the progression and an is the place that ocuppies n (the inpnum) in the progression.*

So what I have done is calculate the sum of all the numbers from 1 to inpnum and then substract the sum of all the multiples of 5 from 5 to n.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int inpnum, quotient, sum;

    cout << "Enter the number to print the SUM : ";
    cin >> inpnum;

    // Finds the amount of multiples of 5 from 5 to n
    quotient = inpnum/5;

          // Sum from 1 to n      // Sum from 5 to n of multiples of 5
    sum = (inpnum*(1+inpnum))/2 - (quotient*(5+(quotient)*5))/2;
    cout << "The sum of the numbers is: " << sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks every one but the problem is solved . the mistake was very small. i forget to write "()" in if condition.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int inputnumber = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int count= 1;
    cout<<"Enter the number to print the SUM : ";
    cin>>inputnumber;

    while(count<=inputnumber)
    {
        if ((count % 5)!=0)//here the ()..
        {
            sum = sum + count;
        }
        count = count +1;
    }   
    cout<<"the sum of the numbers are :   "<<sum;

}
```